# To find Id From Selected Datalist Option

Tags: jquery, html

Give me the solution for this here also i cant get id of options tag.
i do lots of code for only to find id from that datalist please help me.

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("browsers").options.id;
    alert(x);
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option id="1" value="Internet Explorer">
    <option id="2" value="Firefox">
    <option id="3" value="Chrome">
    <option id="4" value="Opera">
    <option id="5" value="Safari">
  </datalist>
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Way to complicated in your example. You can just select the `option` by its `value`. And note, the `id` of the `input` is `#code1`, not `#srch1`.

```js
var g = $('#code1').val();
var id = $('#datalist1 option[value=' + g +']').attr('data-id');
// var id = document.querySelector('#datalist1 option[value=' + g +']').dataset.id;

console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="srch1" id="code1" value="b" />
<datalist id="datalist1">
  <option data-id="1" value="a"></option>
  <option data-id="2" value="b"></option>
  <option data-id="3" value="c"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: In your snippet i see the log but i use your code i get outpute id="undefined".

Comment: If it workes here, but not on your own, then there is something wrong in our code. ;) @mayureshkapdule

Comment: can you convert                                                                                       var id = $('#datalist1 option[value=' + g +']').attr('data-id')  into javascript.

Comment: Yes: `var id = document.querySelector('#datalist1 option[value=' + g +']').dataset.id;` @mayureshkapdule

Comment: i fill datalist in javascript and then append to html i think problem occur due to this please sujest....

Comment: I need to see more of your code then. Its hard to say without. @mayureshkapdule